# MongoDB and RDF

Tags: mongodb, rdf, rdfs

I have to use our production database MongoDB to store RDF triples and one related RDFs Schema.

1) MongoDB is only key-valued, so how I can create one collection which fit with one RDF Schema?

2) How I can represent triples in JSON ?

3) Is there any way to execute SPARQL Query with MongoDB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to your second Question: This is one JSON Object with three values:

```
{
 "tagFirstValue" : "first value here",
 "tagSecondValue" : "second value",
 "tagthirdVale" : "third value"
}
```

Instead you could also use an array:

```
{"tag": [ "firstVale", "secondValue", "thirdValue"]}
```

Or use nested Objects:

```
{
 "tagFirstObject" : {"firstObjectTag":"first value here"},
 "tagSecondObjec" : {"secondObjectTag":"second value here"},
 "tagthirdObjec" : {"thirdObjectTag":"third value here"},
}
```

Its up to you how you define your schema.

In the same way you should create a collection that fit to your RDF Schema, so this is to Question one.

to Question three:  I think the best will be to use a mongodb-driver for the programming language of your choise and transform the SPARQL Query into a MongoDB query.